# How to colour a CUBE ?!

Tags: combinatorics

As I remember, this question was asked by my Mathematics teacher to the whole class and we discussed this question "only" in a whole lecture.
A cube, $6$ non distinguishable faces, is given. All we need to tell is the number of ways in which its faces can be coloured with $6$ different colours. 
$1$. faces are to be coloured... and not edges !! 
$2$. A face must be coloured with exactly one colour. 
$3$. All six colours are to be used, say Blue, Green, Red, Yellow, Orange and White. as in the Rubik's cube.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with probability.

Comment: Does rotating the cube in space count as a "different" coloring?

Comment: Yes, just tell the number of different colourings...

Comment: If one configuration can be rotated to obtain another, are they distinct or no (I assume no, but want to make sure)? Must all six colors be used?

Comment: Please read the question again...

Comment: @AbcDexter: WHAT does it have to do with probability? Try "nothing" instead of "everything".

Comment: @AbcDexter Your edited post says the faces are not distinguishable. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @AbcDexter, if you wanted people to help you and answer your question, it would help if you would answer their clarifications. (Also, if you would accept their criticism of your tag choice, because this is combinatorics, not probability)

Comment: @AbcDexter The Fibonacci numbers have application to pineapples. A question about Fibonacci numbers will not be tagged pineapples. The tags indicate essential subject matter, not the incidental. It lets answerers know the required expertise.

Comment: Ok, "nothing" instead of "everything"...

Comment: @Henning thanks for the answer...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with probability and has a simple solution with combinatorics...see my answer for that

Comment: @hawk , Henning already gave the correct solution. Thanks.

Comment: @AbcDexter I know he gave a solution and a damn good one at that...but it doesn't hurt to provide another solution...afterall that is what this community is about

Comment: Ok, what's your approach ?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One approach: First imagine that the cube is fixed in space and cannot rotate. Then there are clearly $6!$ ways to distribute colors on the faces. But once we allow the cube to rotate, we find that we have counted each combination many times, namely one for each way the cube can be oriented in space. Each color combination has $6\cdot 4$ possible orientations, namely 6 directions the black face can point in, times 4 ways to then rotate the cube around the axis that passes through the center of that face. So the number of combinations is
$$ \frac{6!}{4\cdot 6} = 5\times 3\times 2 = 30 $$

---

As another approach, we can divide into two cases: Either the black and the white face are neighbors, or they are opposite each other. If they are neighbors, we can choose to orient the cube with the black face up and the white face towards us, which completely specifies its orientation. Then the remaining 4 colors can be distributed in $4!$ ways.

If the black and white face are opposite, then orient the cube with the black face up, white face down and *red* face towards us. Then there remaining 3 colors can be distributed in $3!$ ways. So the number of combinations is

$$ 4! + 3! = 24 + 6 = 30 $$

Comment: And the answer is correct ^_^

Comment: I still don't know, how my teacher convinced me that the solution is exactly 1.

Answer (score 3):

Call the six colors $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.$ Put the cube on the table so that face $1$ is at the
bottom. Consider face $2.$ If it is at the top then we can rotate the cube about a vertical
axis so that face 3 is in front. Now the cube is fixed. There are $3!=6$ ways to
complete the coloring. Now, suppose that face $2$ is a neighbor of $1.$ The we rotate the
cube so that $2$ is in front. Now the cube is fixed, and the coloring can be completed
in $4!=24$ ways. Altogether, there are $6+24=30$ distinct colorings of the cube by
six colors.

Answer (score 2):

There are $6!$ ways to color a cube, but we get many overcountings, and we want distinct colourings, so there are $24$ ways in which we can orient a cube. So, $\dfrac{6!}{24}=30$ ways of coloring the cube distinctly.

Comment: I understand the spatial arrangement. correct ...